# How to convert unix/epoch timestamp into date string in Apache Phoenix SQL

Tags: sql, timestamp, hbase, apache-phoenix

We have created Phoenix views on top of Hbase tables and querying the data. One of the the columns holds epoch timestamp data and we need to convert it into a valid date format, couldn't find any appropriate functions, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If type of "*the column holds epoch timestamp data*" is INTEGER or BIGINT, you can use:

`CAST("epoch_time" AS TIMESTAMP)`

if its type is `VARCHAR`, you should first convert value to number through `TO_NUMBER()`
built-in function, i.e.

`CAST(TO_NUMBER("epoch_time") AS TIMESTAMP)`